# Conditonal Formatting - Comparing 2 Dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, date-comparison

I'm working on comparing 2 dates (Column A and Column B) where the condition is if the **date deposited (column B)** is more than **2 days** from the actual **date of sale (column A)**, then column B **font color** will be turn **red**. Please see below link. I hope you can help me with this. Thank you so much in advance.

[Excel File-Comparing 2 Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhtIk.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please post what you have tried so far so we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Grab all of columns A:B then create a conditional formatting rule based on the following formula.

```
=($B1-$A1)>2
```

If you want the difference to be two *working* or *business* days then use [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/networkdays-intl-function-a9b26239-4f20-46a1-9ab8-4e925bfd5e28) which counts inclusive days between two dates and can optionally allow for a holiday list. The following does not use a holiday list but excludes Saturday and Sunday from consideration.

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL($A1, $B1, 1)>2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula in the conditional format, something like

```
A1+2>b1
```